Geometry Math Problem Part 2
Okay! So here is my question. Prove that the exterior angle bisector of a triangle is parallel to the third side if and only if
the triangle is isosceles. That is, in the figure below, show that $\overline{\text{AY}} \parallel \overline{\text{BC}}$ if and
only if $\overline{\text{AB}} \cong \overline{\text{
AC}}$. Note: remember to prove both directions.
And I am given this diagram.

So I haven't gotten very far, yet but this is what I have done. I added on to the diagram like this.

Okay so this is what I know so far and why I have done it.
I know that $\overline{\text{AY}}$ is the angle bisector of ∡XAC
=> assume $\overline{\text{AY}} \parallel \overline{\text{BC}}$ (this I showed by adding the little blue arrow things)
At this point (I was told it could help to assume that triangle ABC is isosceles.
So $\overline{\text{AB}} \cong \overline{\text{AC}}$
I added the two β at points B and C because assuming the triangle is an isosceles then we know that these two angles have to be the same.
This is where I am stuck, I'm not too sure on how to proceed to finish the question. Any help would be amazing. Thanks in advance!

The two relevant rules are corresponding angles: gives you that $\beta$ equals the top copy of $\alpha$, and opposite interior angles, which gives the other equality.

One approach: prove first that external and internal bisectors are always perpendicular; then prove that isosceles triangles always have apex internal bisectors perpendicular to the base.

For if and only is statements you have to prove two statements. In this case, the two statements are as follows: if $ABC$ is isosceles then $AY$ is parallel to $BC$; if $AY$ is parallel to $BC$ then $ABC$ is isosceles.
To prove the first statement, we assume $ABC$ is isosceles and look to show that this implies $AY$ is parallel to $BC$. Note that in an isosceles triangle two angles are equal, as you labeled in your picture we will call these $\beta$. Let us call the angle $BAC$ $\gamma$. We then know that $\gamma + 2\alpha = 180^\circ$ because $BX$ is a line. We also know that $\gamma + 2\beta = 180^\circ$ because the sum of interior angles of a triangle add up to 180 degrees. It is then not too hard to show that $\alpha = \beta$. Then, because they $AY$ and $BC$ make the same angle with the same line, they are parallel.
Now we have to prove the other direction. We will assume $AY$ is parallel to $BC$ and we will look to show that $ABC$ is isosceles. Because we assumed $AY$ and $BC$ are parallel, we know that $\angle XAY = \angle ABC$. To show $ABC$ is isosceles, we will show $\angle ABC = \angle ACB$. I will not give you the whole proof as I think you have enough information to do it yourself, but feel free to ask questions.

Thanks! Okay so after reading I have understood what you explained. So would I essentially just flip everything? So starting I would extend AY line to the right and labeled it V. So we know that because all angles on straight line have equal 180 degrees, angles θ. And because of Alternate (exterior) angles we know that θ = β. This is where I got, I'm not sure if I have proven it enough? Or if I am correct.

I’m not entirely sure if I understand your argument, if $\theta$ represents $\angle ACB$ then yes you are done because you have shown that the triangle has 2 equal angles and hence 2 equal sides. But just like in the first direction you will use that the sum of angles in a triangle and the angle of a straight line are equal to 180 degrees.

From your diagram, the exterior angle is $2\alpha$.
This is equal to the sum of the two opposite interior angles, so $2\alpha=2\beta$ and therefore $\alpha=\beta$.
We now have two alternate angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which are equal if and only if produced by parallel lines.
Being an if and only if statement, this meets the prove in both directions requirement.
The proof is complete.
